# Unable to access the admin section of my new joomla 3x site in localhost

Tags: joomla

I have trouble with my new Joomla 3.x site (installed in localhost (WAMP 2.4) the day before).
I can't access the admin section of my site

```
Error You cannot access the private section of this site".
```

I changed my password (MD5) but no positive result.
Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With so little information you give, do I ask a question? It may be that the user you are accessing not have permission to enter the administrator.

Comment: No no I am the Super User and it is well mentioned in phpmyadmin > users (table) > 1st row ( name = Super User , user = admin ...)

Comment: What do you mean by "I changed my password"? Can  you login to the front end?

Comment: I think you installed admin tools, try to disable it and its plugins from #__extension table , and also you can remove .htaccess file too

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Elin i thought it was a password issue so  I entered the **phpMyAdmin**  to joomla DB ,to users table and changed the password  with function MD5 ? That is what i did but without positive result

Comment: @Silverboy.ir  I didn't understand , do you mean I have to go to phpMyAdmin ,to joomla DB , to _extension table  and delete com_admin row ??

Comment: No Joomla does not use md5 and also if you can login to the front end it 's not a password issue. Lodder is right about asking on JSE.